# I mistakenly issued a git branch --set-upsteam-to, what did that do?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to get better at using Git. And I'm also starting to get into open-source development. I found an open-source project on GitHub that I thought I'd join. I forked the repo, then cloned it onto my machine. Next I tried to set up my remote to point to the original repo on GitHub so I could fetch/pull from there. But I made a mistake in performing the set-upstream command. I first issued a `git remote add upsteam <the Git URL>`. Then I fetched upsteam, then issues a `git branch --set-upsteam-to=...`

Please note, I used **upsteam**, not **upstream**.

And yet Git didn't issue any errors. What I realized my mistake, then reissued the commands using **upstream**. But what in heck did I do to Git and the repo on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't do anything bad or irreparable.

A remote Git repo has a URL. That's a pain to use, so it's nice to make up a name for it. That name is *absolutely arbitrary*. Typically we use the name `origin` for the direct corresponding remote Git repo and the name `upstream` for the original repo from which our repo is a fork, but you could use `heybaburiba` and it wouldn't make the slightest difference. It's just a name that you are using as a shorthand.

So if you happen to say

```
git remote add upsteam <the Git URL>
```

you're just assigning that URL an arbitrary name `upsteam`. That's perfectly fine, and you are then able to say things like `git fetch upsteam`, `git push -u upsteam master`, and all other commands that expect the name of a remote.

If you're sorry you said that, delete that remote and create a remote with a different name. It's only a name!

If you're curious about what names you've defined, just say

```
git remove -v
```

and you will see a list of names and URLs.

Comment: Oh, thank you, @matt! I thought that `upstream` was a proper command. I did not realize that it was only a name. Dang, that makes a significant difference.

Comment: Also the word "upstream" is used both formally and informally in Git in sooooo many ways, it's really confusing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream